# Simple qt gui; repeated widget

Tags: c++, qt

I am relatively new to qt, but is trying to make a simple gui, where parameters are typed in and then written to a text file.

At some point I want to read in *n* sets of parameters of the following form

1) x_min x_max y_min y_max t_min t_max

2) x_min x_max y_min y_max t_min t_max

...

n) x_min x_max y_min y_max t_min t_max

where the numbers are of type QLabel and the rest is QSpinBoxes. The number of rows are decided by the user but *0>= n <=50*. I would like to show only *n* rows such that unused rows are not displayed.

I need an efficient way of of dealing with this and particular reading the information for each line with a minimum of harcodeing.

My idea is to create a new widget class (newRowClass), which has the information for each row and then place it in a QVector. Then I could loop through the QVector and and read the information for each row - Here the interface for each row should be the same, which would make it relatively efficient. However, I have problems organizing this efficiently and I am not sure I am heading in the right direction.

All ideas/suggestions on how to do this are highly appreciated.

All the best,

Bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a different path for the implementation if that is ok. Rather than make a repeating group of widgets use a table to allow the user to enter data.

First off I recommend reading a bit about [Qt Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-classes). This will give you a bit more information on how to organize your data.

Next I would recommend using either a [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) or [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) if you need to support different View classes. If you use the `QAbstractTableModel` just set it on as the `model` on your [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html).

Ensure you correctly implement the `model` to ensure your data is editable, e.g. Read more about `Qt::ItemIsEditable`

That should point you in the right direction to have an series of rows which you can customize (e.g. can the row count in your `model`) and can be edited to allow the user to input the x, y, t min/max values.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a widget representing a row, comprising your different inputs "min", "max". Add public methods to get these user inputs.

Then in your main form you add several instances of this widget within a scroll area. You keep the pointers your all your instances in a list and you will be able to iterate over them to retrieve the informations you want.

This is pretty convenient and evolutions to a cell will be easier.